# iPhone OS does not match app deployment version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ibeacon

I am using the Xcode 7.0 beta, trying to use iBeacon thing. I don't have developer account, but heard the beta can run apps on your device. But when I was trying to run the program, device OS version is lower than deployment target my phone is iPhone 5 ios 8.4 which is the most new version. however the deployment target is IOS 9.0. How can i fix this problem.

Comment: Set the deployment target to iOS 8.4 or lower.

Comment: working solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519330/3879847

Answer (score 13):

There are always two solutions when faced with this:

1. Set the deployment target lower in Xcode
2. Use a device that matches the deployment target in the project.

1: To set the deployment target, go to the General settings for your app.  In the "Deployment Info" section, change the "Deployment Target" field to at least 8.4 (since that is the device you are using), or lower if you have more devices you want to test on.

2: To update your device to a beta release of iOS, you'll need to go through your Apple developer account (doesn't have to be a paid account) and follow the instructions there to upgrade.

Note: upgrading your primary device (like your ONLY PHONE) to a beta is generally a risky/terrible idea. Option #1 is really the one you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that even all other targets including Pods deployment target is matched with you project deployment version, in order to avoid any kind of bizarre issues.