# I lowered iOS deployment target version to run the app in an iPhone but the version change is not applied

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment

As you can see in the screenshot below, iOS version of my target iPhone is 9.0.2.

The deployment target version of the project was originally 9.2, so I changed it to 9.0 and then to 8.4 again.

The target selection menu on top left still prompts a message saying 'version is lower than ...'. I tried saving again by command+S, pulling out the USB cable and re-executing Xcode but nothing works.

I have both 7.3 and 8.0 Xcode app; tried both. The Xcode in the screenshot is version 7.3. Do you have any idea to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select your Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target.
[image]

Comment: @YeongchanJeon you should accept this answer since it solved your issue

Comment: How do you "Select your Target"? The latest Xcode doesn't appear to have a "Targets" section like the screenshot shows.