# Visual Studio Preview 2022 will not let my change deployment target

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just installed Visual Studio Preview for the MacOS yesterday. The simulators work fine, but I can't run on any devices I have (both IOS and Android). It keeps saying that the OS version is lower than the deployment target.
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWBeI.png)

It doesn't make sense; one of the devices I tried was a Galaxy A11 I just got, software version 10. The IOS device has software version 15.4.1. I can't even find what the current deployment target even is. I've checked the info.plist and AndroidManifest files with no success. Yeah I can use the simulators to work on the app but sooner or later I will need to test on a physical device. Can someone point me in the right direction?

If it helps I'm currently running macOS Monterey version 12.3.1.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I've tried to add the Minimum System Version to the info.plist, but that didn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone OS does not match app deployment version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814722/iphone-os-does-not-match-app-deployment-version)

Comment: The comment above references an answer involving XCode. This question is about VS for Mac.
I've entered a VS feedback item about this problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-run-NET-7-iOS-app-on-physical-iP/10262296?viewtype=all

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that the device destinations in the drop-down shown in the question are driven off of whatever XCode command line tools you have set for use before starting VS for Mac.

Presumably if you check your physical device's OS version against the SDK version shown when you type this at the command line will show that the physical device's OS version is lower than the appropriate SDK version shown.

`xcodebuild -showsdks`